# how can I solve this ERROR: Could not build wheels for marius, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, installation, package, python-wheel, install.packages

I'm trying to install Marius python package but encountering the error "ERROR: Could not build wheels for marius, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects" every time. The error message is given:

`

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Processing /home/safrin/marius

Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from marius==0.0.2) (1.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.1 in /home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from marius==0.0.2) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.7.1 in /home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from marius==0.0.2) (1.12.1+cu113)
Requirement already satisfied: omegaconf>=2.2 in /home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from marius==0.0.2) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psutil-5.9.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg (from marius==0.0.2) (5.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: GPUtil>=1.4 in /home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from marius==0.0.2) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/importlib_metadata-4.10.0-py3.8.egg (from marius==0.0.2) (4.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.0.0->marius==0.0.2) (3.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.* in /home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from omegaconf>=2.2->marius==0.0.2) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=5.1.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from omegaconf>=2.2->marius==0.0.2) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in /home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas>=1.1->marius==0.0.2) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas>=1.1->marius==0.0.2) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in /home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas>=1.1->marius==0.0.2) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from torch>=1.7.1->marius==0.0.2) (3.10.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas>=1.1->marius==0.0.2) (1.14.0)

Building wheels for collected packages: marius
  Building wheel for marius (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for marius (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [286 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
      Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius
      copying src/python/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools
      copying src/python/tools/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools
      copying src/python/tools/marius_postprocess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools
      copying src/python/tools/marius_config_generator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools
      copying src/python/tools/marius_predict.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools
      copying src/python/tools/marius_preprocess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/console_scripts
      copying src/python/console_scripts/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/console_scripts
      copying src/python/console_scripts/marius_train.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/console_scripts
      copying src/python/console_scripts/marius_eval.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/console_scripts
      running egg_info
      writing marius.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to marius.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing entry points to marius.egg-info/entry_points.txt
      writing requirements to marius.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to marius.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'marius.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[cod]' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dylib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.gpickle' found anywhere in distribution
      writing manifest file 'marius.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/distribution
      copying src/python/distribution/generate_stubs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/distribution
      copying src/python/distribution/marius_env_info.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/distribution
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/configuration
      copying src/python/tools/configuration/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/configuration
      copying src/python/tools/configuration/constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/configuration
      copying src/python/tools/configuration/datatypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/configuration
      copying src/python/tools/configuration/marius_config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/configuration
      copying src/python/tools/configuration/validation.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/configuration
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/db2graph
      copying src/python/tools/db2graph/marius_db2graph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/db2graph
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/postprocess
      copying src/python/tools/postprocess/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/postprocess
      copying src/python/tools/postprocess/in_memory_exporter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/postprocess
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/prediction
      copying src/python/tools/prediction/link_prediction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/prediction
      copying src/python/tools/prediction/node_classification.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/prediction
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/custom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/dataset_stats.tsv -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/spark_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/spark_converter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/torch_converter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/partitioners
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/partitioners/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/partitioners
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/partitioners/partitioner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/partitioners
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/partitioners/spark_partitioner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/partitioners
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/partitioners/torch_partitioner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/partitioners
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/readers
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/readers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/readers
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/readers/pandas_readers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/readers
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/readers/reader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/readers
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/readers/spark_readers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/readers
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/writers
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/writers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/writers
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/writers/spark_writer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/writers
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/writers/torch_writer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/writers
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/converters/writers/writer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/converters/writers
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/dataset_helpers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/fb15k.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/fb15k_237.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/freebase86m.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/friendster.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/livejournal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/ogb_mag240m.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/ogb_wikikg90mv2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/ogbl_citation2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/ogbl_ppa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/ogbl_wikikg2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/ogbn_arxiv.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/ogbn_papers100m.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/ogbn_products.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      copying src/python/tools/preprocess/datasets/twitter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/tools/preprocess/datasets
      running build_ext
      -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.3.109
      -- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda-11.3/bin/nvcc - skipped
      -- Detecting CUDA compile features
      -- Detecting CUDA compile features - done
      -- Torch Version: 2.0.1+cu117
      -- project_CUDA_THIRD_PARTY_HEADERS /home/safrin/marius/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/atomics.cuh;/home/safrin/marius/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/index_info.cuh;/home/safrin/marius/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/reducer.cuh;/home/safrin/marius/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/segment_csr_cuda.h;/home/safrin/marius/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/segment_max.h;/home/safrin/marius/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/utils.cuh
      -- project_CUDA_THIRD_PARTY_SOURCES /home/safrin/marius/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/segment_csr_cuda.cu;/home/safrin/marius/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/segment_max.cpp
      -- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.5") found components: Development Interpreter Development.Module Development.Embed
      -- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda-11.3 (found version "11.3")
      -- Caffe2: CUDA detected: 11.3
      -- Caffe2: CUDA nvcc is: /usr/local/cuda-11.3/bin/nvcc
      -- Caffe2: CUDA toolkit directory: /usr/local/cuda-11.3
      -- Caffe2: Header version is: 11.3
      -- /usr/local/cuda-11.3/lib64/libnvrtc.so shorthash is 1ea278b5
      -- USE_CUDNN is set to 0. Compiling without cuDNN support
      -- Autodetected CUDA architecture(s):  8.0
      -- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: -gencode;arch=compute_80,code=sm_80
      CMake Warning at /tmp/pip-build-env-kllncm3i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:22 (message):
        static library kineto_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND not found.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        /tmp/pip-build-env-kllncm3i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:127 (append_torchlib_if_found)
        CMakeLists.txt:99 (find_package)
  
  
  -- Found Torch: /tmp/pip-build-env-kllncm3i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so
  -- PYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE:_gcc
  -- PYBIND11_STDLIB:_libstdcpp
  -- PYBIND11_BUILD_ABI:_cxxabi1011
  -- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: -DVERSION_INFO=\"0.0.2\" -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
  -- Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/include/python3.9
  -- /home/safrin/marius/src/cpp/third_party/pybind11/.git does not exist. Initializing pybind11 submodule ...
  Submodule 'src/cpp/third_party/pybind11' (https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git) registered for path 'pybind11'
  Cloning into '/home/safrin/marius/src/cpp/third_party/pybind11'...
  Submodule path 'pybind11': checked out 'e08a58111dbea38d667b209f7543864d51a3b185'
  -- /home/safrin/marius/src/cpp/third_party/spdlog/.git does not exist. Initializing spdlog submodule ...
  Submodule 'src/cpp/third_party/spdlog' (https://github.com/gabime/spdlog.git) registered for path 'spdlog'
  Cloning into '/home/safrin/marius/src/cpp/third_party/spdlog'...
  Submodule path 'spdlog': checked out 'c5abaeddcaa67e885de99db583396899a0cf43e6'
  -- /home/safrin/marius/src/cpp/third_party/googletest/.git does not exist. Initializing googletest submodule ...
  Submodule 'src/cpp/third_party/googletest' (https://github.com/google/googletest.git) registered for path 'googletest'
  Cloning into '/home/safrin/marius/src/cpp/third_party/googletest'...
  Submodule path 'googletest': checked out '23ef29555ef4789f555f1ba8c51b4c52975f0907'
  -- /home/safrin/marius/src/cpp/third_party/parallel-hashmap/.git does not exist. Initializing parallel-hashmap submodule ...
  Submodule 'src/cpp/third_party/parallel-hashmap' (https://github.com/greg7mdp/parallel-hashmap.git) registered for path 'parallel-hashmap'
  Cloning into '/home/safrin/marius/src/cpp/third_party/parallel-hashmap'...
  Submodule path 'parallel-hashmap': checked out 'f7fbefac75c9f29538bfe7b65f3b67c082c127d6'
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Found Python: /usr/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.5") found components: Interpreter
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  -- pybind11 v2.6.3 dev1
  -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO
  -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO - Success
  -- Build spdlog: 1.8.5
  -- Build type: Release
  -- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5")
  -- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")
  -- TORCH_PYTHON_LIBRARY: /tmp/pip-build-env-kllncm3i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so
  -- Configuring done (16.9s)
  -- Generating done (0.1s)
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/safrin/marius/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  [  0%] Building CXX object src/cpp/third_party/spdlog/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/spdlog.cpp.o
  [  1%] Building CXX object src/cpp/third_party/spdlog/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/stdout_sinks.cpp.o
  [  2%] Building CXX object src/cpp/third_party/spdlog/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/color_sinks.cpp.o
  [  2%] Building CXX object src/cpp/third_party/spdlog/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/file_sinks.cpp.o
  [  3%] Building CXX object src/cpp/third_party/spdlog/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/async.cpp.o
  [  3%] Building CXX object src/cpp/third_party/spdlog/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/fmt.cpp.o
  [  5%] Building CXX object src/cpp/third_party/spdlog/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/cfg.cpp.o
  [  6%] Linking CXX static library libspdlog.a
  [  6%] Built target spdlog
  [  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/common/util.cpp.o
  [  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/configuration/config.cpp.o
  [  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/configuration/options.cpp.o
  [ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/configuration/util.cpp.o
  [ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/data/batch.cpp.o
  [ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/data/graph.cpp.o
  [ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/data/ordering.cpp.o
  [ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/data/dataloader.cpp.o
  [ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/data/samplers/negative.cpp.o
  [ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/data/samplers/edge.cpp.o
  [ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/data/samplers/neighbor.cpp.o
  [ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/marius.cpp.o
  [ 17%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/activation.cpp.o
  [ 18%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/decoders/edge/comparators.cpp.o
  [ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/decoders/edge/decoder_methods.cpp.o
  [ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/decoders/edge/complex.cpp.o
  [ 21%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/decoders/edge/distmult.cpp.o
  [ 21%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/decoders/edge/edge_decoder.cpp.o
  [ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/decoders/edge/relation_operators.cpp.o
  [ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/decoders/edge/transe.cpp.o
  [ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/decoders/node/noop_node_decoder.cpp.o
  [ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/encoders/encoder.cpp.o
  [ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/embedding/embedding.cpp.o
  [ 27%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/initialization.cpp.o
  [ 27%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/feature/feature.cpp.o
  [ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/gnn/gat_layer.cpp.o
  [ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/layer.cpp.o
  [ 30%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/gnn/gcn_layer.cpp.o
  [ 31%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/gnn/layer_helpers.cpp.o
  [ 32%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/reduction/concat.cpp.o
  [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/gnn/graph_sage_layer.cpp.o
  [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/gnn/rgcn_layer.cpp.o
  [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/loss.cpp.o
  [ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/layers/reduction/linear.cpp.o
  [ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/model.cpp.o
  [ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/regularizer.cpp.o
  [ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/nn/optim.cpp.o
  [ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/pipeline/pipeline.cpp.o
  [ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/pipeline/evaluator.cpp.o
  [ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/pipeline/graph_encoder.cpp.o
  [ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/pipeline/trainer.cpp.o
  [ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/pipeline/pipeline_gpu.cpp.o
  [ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/pipeline/pipeline_cpu.cpp.o
  [ 43%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/reporting/reporting.cpp.o
  [ 43%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/storage/checkpointer.cpp.o
  [ 45%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/storage/io.cpp.o
  [ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/storage/buffer.cpp.o
  [ 47%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/storage/graph_storage.cpp.o
  [ 47%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/segment_csr_cuda.cu.o
  [ 48%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cpp/src/storage/storage.cpp.o
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marius.dir/src/cuda/third_party/pytorch_scatter/segment_max.cpp.o
  [ 51%] Linking CXX shared library /home/safrin/marius/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/libmarius.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_intel_ilp64
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_intel_thread
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_core
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/marius.dir/build.make:917: /home/safrin/marius/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius/libmarius.so] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:306: CMakeFiles/marius.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:588: CMakeFiles/bindings.dir/rule] Error 2
  make: *** [Makefile:309: bindings] Error 2
  ['-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/safrin/marius/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/marius', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=TRUE', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH=TRUE', '-DUSE_CUDA=TRUE', '-DUSE_OMP=TRUE', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=$ORIGIN']
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kllncm3i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 208, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kllncm3i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 194, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kllncm3i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 81, in <module>
      setup(
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kllncm3i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kllncm3i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 30, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "setup.py", line 73, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(["cmake", "--build", ".", "--target", "bindings"] + build_args, cwd=self.build_temp)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--target', 'bindings', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j128']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
  [end of output]



note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for marius
Failed to build marius
ERROR: Could not build wheels for marius, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

`

I tried the following things:

```
1. checked dependencies (Project Requirements) CUDA >= 10.1 CuDNN >= 7 pytorch >= 1.8 python >= 3.6 GCC >= 7 (On Linux) or Clang 12.0 (On MacOS) cmake >= 3.12 make >= 3.8) 

I have  --> CUDA11.3, torch Version: 1.12.1+cu113, Python 3.8.10,gcc (Ubuntu 8.4.0-3ubuntu2) 8.4.0, cmake Version: 3.26.4, GNU Make 4.2.1 
2. pip3 install --upgrade pip3 setuptools wheel 3. pip3 install --user testresources
4. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/safrin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Still I am unable to fix the error to install the package. Any other possible solution?